# Newtonsoft Json deserialize, JProperty and JObjects?

Tags: c#, .net, json.net

Im trying to deserialize a json-text/string by simply doing:

```
var jObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(myjsonstring);
```

The thing is that I later on need to iterate through the jObject.. since I will "serialize" it back to XML later on using a speciall format. But this deserialization give me a JProperty and a JObject for each "node" in the json.. is there any way to tell the serializer that Im only intressted of the JProperties or the JObjects.

=============

**Edit**

To explain it abit more..
the thing is that if i later on would type the following in the VS-watch:

```
jObject
```

It would give the result:

```
{ "myjson":{ "mytest":"myvalue" } }
```

And

```
jObject.Children().First()
```

would give me the following result/respons from the watch:

```
{"myjson":{ "mytest":"myvalue" } }
```

But the result/respons that I think would be more logical would be:

```
{ "mytest":"myvalue" }
```

Since thats the actuall Child object of the "myjson"-property.. so the question is.. how do I get that behavior that I actually want? or am I missing something?

Comment: I don't understand what exactly do you need and why. Could you add an example?

Answer (score 0):

To access value inside JObject I use JToken :

```
JToken child = jObject["myjson"];
```

If you want retrieve the value in a string you can serialize the JToken

```
string childInString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(child);
```

Hope that help.